# Cakephp findByEmail not working

Tags: cakephp

I am having this strange issue; I am unable to retrieve emails from my database. I tried using findByEmail but I am getting an empty array. I tried using find('first') with email as the condition but getting an empty array as well. I am able to retrieve everything except emails.

my UsersController code: `$user = $this->User->findByEmail($this->data['User']['email']);`

to test the function I tried: `

```
$me = 'variasoft@gmail.com';
$user = $this->User->findByEmail($me);
debug($me);
```

debug() returns an empty array.

I am not sure what the problem is.

`

Comment: Whats the column name where you store email addresses?

Comment: are you sure that the name of the column in the users table is 'email'? Are you sure that the email stored in the record is identical to the email you are searching? No additional spaces, same encoding etc...

Comment: Column name is 'email' , I am wondering if the encoding may be the issue, mine for the email column is armscii8_bin

Comment: are you sure you are loading your model?  $this->loadModel('User'); and then debug($user); not debug($me);

Comment: it should be `debug($user);`, not `debug($me);`

Comment: try posting the generated query and then try it directly in mysql. Also consider what @cornelb writes about the debug line: is it just a typo or you actually are debugging `$me` variable?

Comment: Yes debug($user), i typed that here off the top of my head so thats why. debug($me) returns the email, but debug($user) returns null.

I dont need to use $this->LoadModel('User'); , I am able to retrieve all the other columns if I use find('first') , however I am unable to retrieve the emails for some reason...

Comment: what about the generated query?

Comment: How do I get the generated query?

Comment: if you have enabled debug mode (and it must be so otherwise you could not see the debug messages) you must see the all the queries at the end of the page. This happens in the default layout, if you have changed the default layout and removed the line that outputs the sql then you won't see them, but I can't know this

Comment: Another way to do it is immediately after your call to findByEmail:  
`$dataSource = $this->User->getDatasource();
$logs = $dataSource->getLog();
$lastLog = end($logs['log']); debug($lastLog);`

Comment: Did you add the `email` column in your database recently? If so, set Cake debug to `2` in `app/Config/core.php` to take the modification into account.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to the encoding used. I originally had armscii8_bin as encoding, when I changed to utf8_unicode_ci the variable $users became populated when I used the following code:

```
            if (!empty($this->request->data['User']['email'])) {
            $user = $this->User->findByEmail($this->data['User']['email']);
```

Result:  `array(
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '534395',
        'parent_id' => '534394',
        'created' => '2014-05-07 13:01:10',
        'modified' => '2014-05-07 13:01:10',
        'lastlogin' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        'first_name' => 'ascsadasd',
        'last_name' => 'sadascascsa',
        'middle_name' => 'saas',
        'email' => 'variasoft@gmail.com',
        'phone' => '0',
        'country' => '',
        'username' => 'trayvon',
        'activation_code' => '',
        'status' => false,
        'password_reset' => '',
        'tokenhash' => '',
        'role' => '#artiste',
        'reset_password_token' => '',
        'token_created_at' => '',
        'summary' => 'dvdsvsdfv ',
        'role_model' => 'dsfv sdfvv dsfv sdv ',
        'fav_song' => 'dsdv sddsfsd',
        'trailer' => 'vdssdvddsds',
        'genre_id' => '5',
        'image' => null
    ),
    'Parent' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '534394',
        'parent_id' => null,
        'created' => '2014-05-07 12:35:01',
        'modified' => '2014-05-07 12:56:03',
        'lastlogin' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        'first_name' => 'safasfs',
        'last_name' => 'fasfasfcasf',
        'middle_name' => 'safasfasfasf',
        'email' => 'herrhorace@gmail.com',
        'phone' => '123456',
        'country' => '',
        'username' => 'Memrise2',
        'activation_code' => '',
        'status' => false,
        'password_reset' => '',
        'tokenhash' => '',
        'role' => 'manager',
        'reset_password_token' => '',
        'token_created_at' => '',
        'summary' => null,
        'role_model' => null,
        'fav_song' => null,
        'trailer' => null,
        'genre_id' => null,
        'image' => null
    ),
    'Genre' => array(
        'id' => '5',
        'name' => 'Soul'
    ),
    'Children' => array(),
    'Image' => array(),
    'Like' => array(),
    'Comment' => array(),
    'Customize' => array()
)`